# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 22

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i am aware that there is a lot of threads about this exception however, i would like people to view my code and assist me in where i am specifically going wrong.

Here is my code for trying to store my users input to an sqlite database and then transfer the code and display it in a new activity.  Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong and why this error keeps occuring? (error in title)

```
   Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();


            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String getid = res.getString(0);
            String getlt = res.getString(1);
            String getpt = res.getString(2);
            String getqty = res.getString(3);
            String getdur = res.getString(4);
            String getst = res.getString(5);
            String getet = res.getString(6);


            if ( res != null && res.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    buffer.append(getid);
                    buffer.append(getlt);
                    buffer.append(getpt);
                    buffer.append(getqty);
                    buffer.append(getdur);
                    buffer.append(getst);
                    buffer.append(getet);
                } while (res.moveToNext());
            }


            Intent TransferData = new Intent(getBaseContext(), screen4.class);
            TransferData.putExtra("ID", getid);
            TransferData.putExtra("LineType", getlt);
            TransferData.putExtra("PackageType", getpt);
            TransferData.putExtra("Quantity", getqty);
            TransferData.putExtra("Duration", getdur);
            TransferData.putExtra("Starttime",getst);
            TransferData.putExtra("endtime", getet);

            startActivity(TransferData);
        }
    });
}
```

}

ATTEMPT 2 INSIDE DO BLOCK :

```
 Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();


            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();


            if ( res != null && res.moveToNext()) {
                do {

                    String getid = res.getString(0);
                    String getlt = res.getString(1);
                    String getpt = res.getString(2);
                    String getqty = res.getString(3);
                    String getdur = res.getString(4);
                    String getst = res.getString(5);
                    String getet = res.getString(6);

                    buffer.append(getid);
                    buffer.append(getlt);
                    buffer.append(getpt);
                    buffer.append(getqty);
                    buffer.append(getdur);
                    buffer.append(getst);
                    buffer.append(getet);

                    Intent TransferData = new Intent(getBaseContext(), screen4.class);
                    TransferData.putExtra("ID", getid);
                    TransferData.putExtra("LineType", getlt);
                    TransferData.putExtra("PackageType", getpt);
                    TransferData.putExtra("Quantity", getqty);
                    TransferData.putExtra("Duration", getdur);
                    TransferData.putExtra("Starttime",getst);
                    TransferData.putExtra("endtime", getet);

                    startActivity(TransferData);

                } while (res.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a unclear.

In your code there is:

```
String getid = res.getString(0);
String getlt = res.getString(1);
//bla bla bla
```

I believe they should be inside the do block.

You have tried to access the column data without moving the `Cursor` to first position.

**You must call `Cursor#moveToFirst();` before reading any value from the `Cursor`.**

Comment: I tried what you said and i was getting an error as because the strings are declared inside the DO block now they are not accessible by the intent. so i tried to move the intent inside the DO block too but it is still crashing. I have put an update on the code in my initial post

Comment: im only a beginner. thats very helpful isnt it.

Comment: I know you are a beginner. But you must have basic knowledge of Java before trying Android.

Comment: so your going to offer no help?

Comment: I tried, but I don't think I can. I can't teach you how to use strings and loops.

Comment: is the code that i have for transfering the data to my next activity using intent correct?

Comment: Looks correct, but you should not do it inside the loop.

Comment: i dont have it in the loop.. i was simply trying what the guy who commented this answer told me. have a look at my initial code

Comment: Basically. i have the data storing successfully in my sqlite database. I am simply trying to display the data stored in my next activity

Comment: Instead of putting all extras, use TransferData.putExtra( "data" , buffer.toString());

Comment: i need to put all extras as well as i will be displaying each input in a different text box on the next screen

Comment: Then you'll need to use different string buffers for different fields.

Comment: I will give that a go and see. did you say my loops is incorrect? thanks btw!

Comment: yeah still getting the same error to do with the cursor index

Comment: Use cursor.moveToFirst() before getting any data from the cursor.

Comment: That works thanks @Nabin Bhandari!! Although just another thing.. it is now displaying everryyy value of every stored row.. how do i code it so that it only shows the data of the last stored record?

Comment: use `buffer.setLength(0);` in the beginning of the loop to clear old data.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help @Nabin Bhandari !!